# Is there a way to make "rake routes" look better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake, command

I am always forced to make my terminal window two dual monitors wide just to see read them right. I'm not a stickler for buttery GUI's, but this is ridiculous.

Is there a pretty print for this command?

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT: The answer below was packaged into the [html_routes](https://github.com/pierre-pretorius/html_routes) gem which supports Rails 3 and 4.**

The code below was made with the current **Rails 3.2.3**, groups by controller and looks awesome.  Remember to change the `<Your APP>` to your app name and add gem 'syntax' to your Gemfile.

[image: Sample image]

```
desc 'Pretty print out all defined routes in match order, with names. Target specific controller with CONTROLLER=x.'

task :routes => :environment do
if ENV['CONTROLLER']
  all_routes = <Your APP>::Application.routes.select { |route| route.defaults[:controller] == ENV['CONTROLLER'] }
else
  all_routes = <Your APP>::Application.routes
end

convertor = Syntax::Convertors::HTML.for_syntax "ruby"

File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "routes.html"), "w") do |f|
  f.puts "<html><head><title>Your APP</title>
         <style type='text/css'>
         body { background-color: #333; color: #FFF; }
         table { border: 1px solid #777; background-color: #111; }
         td, th { font-size: 11pt; text-align: left; padding-right: 10px; }
         th { font-size: 12pt; }
         pre { maring: 0; padding: 0; }
         .contrl_head { font-size: 14pt; padding: 15px 0 5px 0; }
         .contrl_name { color: #ACE; }
         .punct { color: #99F; font-weight: bold; }
         .symbol { color: #7DD; }
         .regex { color: #F66; }
         .string { color: #F99; }4
         </style></head>
         <body>"

  last_contrl = nil

  routes = all_routes.routes.collect do |route|
    if !route.requirements.empty?
      if route.requirements[:controller] != last_contrl
        f.puts "</table>" if last_contrl
        last_contrl = route.requirements[:controller]
        f.puts "<div class='contrl_head'><b>Controller: <span class='contrl_name'>#{last_contrl}</span></b></div>" +
               "<table width='100%' border='0'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Verb</th><th>Path</th><th>Requirements</th></tr>" 
      end

      reqs = route.requirements.inspect
      verb = route.verb.source
      verb = verb[1..(verb.length-2)] if verb
      r = { :name => route.name, :verb => verb, :path => route.path, :reqs => reqs }
      f.puts "<tr><td width='12%'><b>#{r[:name]}</b></td><td width='5%'><b>#{r[:verb]}</b></td>" +
              "<td width='3%'>#{r[:path]}</td><td width='80%'>#{convertor.convert(r[:reqs])}</td></tr>"
    end
  end

  f.puts "</table></body></html>"
end
end
```

Comment: Dude this is great! Lets see a gem :)

Comment: Add the gem 'syntax' to your Gemfile

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/nicooga/color_routes does it pretty well, I think!

Comment: anything for the rails 4?

Answer (score 9):

## Use the in-built display given by rails

1. Start the server `rails s`
2. **Click on this link**: http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes - this should look a LOT better than in the terminal + you can search through the routes too (which is very handy). Personally, I have saved it as a bookmark.
3. Voila:

[image: This is how it looks like!]

Answer (score 5):

```
Rails 3.1 version, Replace all <YourApp> tag with your application name.

desc 'Pretty print out all defined routes in match order, with names. Target specific controller with CONTROLLER=x.'
task :pretty_routes => :environment do
  all_routes = ENV['CONTROLLER'] ? <YourApp>::Application.routes.select { |route| route.defaults[:controller] == ENV['CONTROLLER'] } : <YourApp>::Application.routes
  routes = all_routes.routes.collect do |route|
    reqs = route.requirements.empty? ? "" : route.requirements.inspect
    {:name => route.name, :verb => route.verb, :path => route.path, :reqs => reqs}
  end
  File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "routes.html"), "w") do |f|
    f.puts "<html><head><title>Rails 3 Routes</title></head><body><table border=1>"
    f.puts "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Verb</th><th>Path</th><th>Requirements</th></tr>"
    routes.each do |r|
      f.puts "<tr><td>#{r[:name]}</td><td>#{r[:verb]}</td><td>#{r[:path]}</td><td>#{r[:reqs]}</td></tr>"
    end
    f.puts "</table></body></html>"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

### Rails 6+

For those, who anyway want to use their terminal to view complicated `rails routes`.

Rails 6 introduced `--expanded` option to print them in a more convenient way.

Here is an example:

```
$ rails routes --expanded
--[ Route 1 ]------------------------------------------------------------
Prefix            | high_scores
Verb              | GET
URI               | /high_scores(.:format)
Controller#Action | high_scores#index
--[ Route 2 ]------------------------------------------------------------
Prefix            | new_high_score
Verb              | GET
URI               | /high_scores/new(.:format)
Controller#Action | high_scores#new
--[ Route 3 ]------------------------------------------------------------
Prefix            | blog
Verb              |
URI               | /blog
Controller#Action | Blog::Engine

[ Routes for Blog::Engine ]
--[ Route 1 ]------------------------------------------------------------
Prefix            | cart
Verb              | GET
URI               | /cart(.:format)
Controller#Action | cart#show
```

And a [link to PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32130).

Comment: That looks awesome. Thanks so much for sharing

Answer (score 4):

I've rewritten the rake routes command slightly to generate a slightly more usable html version of the rake routes output

Create a file `pretty_routes.rake` and put this in `lib/tasks/` and call `rake pretty_routes` and it should be slightly better

```
desc 'Pretty print out all defined routes in match order, with names. Target specific controller with CONTROLLER=x.'
task :pretty_routes => :environment do
  all_routes = ENV['CONTROLLER'] ? ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes.select { |route| route.defaults[:controller] == ENV['CONTROLLER'] } : ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes
  routes = all_routes.collect do |route|
    name = ActionController::Routing::Routes.named_routes.routes.index(route).to_s
    verb = route.conditions[:method].to_s.upcase
    segs = route.segments.inject("") { |str,s| str << s.to_s }
    segs.chop! if segs.length > 1
    reqs = route.requirements.empty? ? "" : route.requirements.inspect
    {:name => name, :verb => verb, :segs => segs, :reqs => reqs}
  end
  File.open(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "routes.html"), "w") do |f|
    f.puts "<html><head><title>Rails Routes</title></head><body><table border=1>"
    f.puts "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Verb</th><th>Segments</th><th>Requirements</th></tr>"
    routes.each do |r|
      f.puts "<tr><td>#{r[:name]}</td><td>#{r[:verb]}</td><td>#{r[:segs]}</td><td>#{r[:reqs]}</td></tr>"
    end
    f.puts "</table></body></html>"
  end
  `open #{File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "routes.html")}`
end
```

The second to last line only works on Mac OSX an in rails 2.x, but it automatically opens the file in your browser.  If you are on a different platform, you will have to change the command.

If you are running Rails 3.x, the second to last line should be

```
 `open #{File.join(Rails.root, "routes.html")}`
```

Comment: ITs clever. And I absolutely give you kudos for this, but I don't like getting all the routes at once. I usually go for a `rake routes | grep somethingSpecific`

Comment: This seems broken with rails3? rake aborted!
undefined method `segments' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Route:0x000001058a9138>

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Lichtamberg: absolutely. I'm still on Rails 2.3.x, rails 3 entirely changed routing, so you will have to modify the solution to work for you.

Comment: Trip: you can always just use find in the browser to narrow it down.  Its basically equivalent to grepping for something in the output of rake routes.

Comment: ah good point. one of these days i'll write something exclusively for the terminal window with pretty colors. thanks anyway

Comment: @Trip - did you write the one with pretty colors? I'd appreciate you paste it here. good idea!

Answer (score 3):

You could use Sextant to print the routes in your browser: https://github.com/schneems/sextant

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 3, you can use : `Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a` (see [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10576105/407213))

Answer (score 1):

Great tip. Thanks.

I prepared working version for **Rails 3.0**. Enjoy.

```
desc 'Pretty print out all defined routes in match order, with names. Target specific controller with CONTROLLER=x.'

task :pretty_routes => :environment do
  all_routes = ENV['CONTROLLER'] ? ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes.select { |route| route.defaults[:controller] == ENV['CONTROLLER'] } : ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes
  routes = all_routes.collect do |route|
    reqs = route.requirements.empty? ? "" : route.requirements.inspect
    {:name => route.name, :verb => route.verb, :path => route.path, :reqs => reqs}
  end
  File.open(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "routes.html"), "w") do |f|
    f.puts "<html><head><title>Rails 3 Routes</title></head><body><table border=1>"
    f.puts "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Verb</th><th>Path</th><th>Requirements</th></tr>"
    routes.each do |r|
      f.puts "<tr><td>#{r[:name]}</td><td>#{r[:verb]}</td><td>#{r[:path]}</td><td>#{r[:reqs]}</td></tr>"
    end
    f.puts "</table></body></html>"
  end
end
```