# Result of `rake routes` in ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, routes, rake

`rake routes` is very slow (30s in my computer) but I need it for routing spec.

So, is there a way to get all routes like rake routes? (or how rake routes works?)

I use Rails 3 and all I have seen is for Rails 3, and I found nothing I can use in the rails doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a`

`.to_a` is optional, it just converts it to an array.

(I found this line in `railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake`)

I use it like :
`routes[10].defaults` => `{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"polls"}`

**Edit** : You can find the (quite hacky) way I do my routing specs here : https://gist.github.com/52ac6d848ce0d9fd52ac

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RSpec, you can use [routing specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-10/docs/routing-specs) in your tests.

Comment: I am doing a global testing of all routes, it's very effective to discover bugs fastly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [rake shell](https://github.com/jugyo/rake-sh); I love it.