# How to generate URL API documents in PDF or HTML from routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to export the URL routes document to the PM,

She needs to read the URL formats in **HTML** format or **PDF** format.

Somehow, the generated API format by **rake routes** its too ugly for general people.

Is there any gem can generate prettier URI Formats ?

I don't need to show the **Prefix** and  **Controller#Action**

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You can find multiple ways here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986997/is-there-a-way-to-make-rake-routes-look-better

Answer (score 0):

When you run rails app, in your browser, hit the wrong URL and get error page - you have all your routes there.

Run your app and go to localhost:3000/somenoneexistingroute

there you have your HTML format[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty list of URI patterns, you can use the command line:

```
rake routes | cut -c41-95 | sort --key=1.10
```

The output of `rake routes` has fixed column widths, so you'll have to tweak the above in order to tailor it for your app's output, but the above example snatches the characters between columns 41 and 95 and alphabetizes them. Just adjust the first number until the slash is the first character on every line, and the second number until the controller names disappear.

The `--key` on the sort ensures that the list is alphabetized on the characters after the slash, it counts 10 characters from the first field (`1.10`), which skips over the HTTP verbs. If you want them in natural order, remove `| sort...` from the command.

If you're using Windows, there are other ways to do this, or you can install the Gnu tools to get cut & sort.